# LAMMPS error "Two fix ave commands using same compute chunk/atom command in incompatible ways"

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software, molecular-modeling, lammps

I am very new to using LAMMPS. I am trying to obtain some simulations. I was using an older code which had ave/spatial fix style. In the new LAMMPS version it doesn't work so I am switching to ave/chunk fix style. Below are the lines where I am using this style.

```
compute a1 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 10.0 units box
compute b1 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 20.0 units box 
fix             4a all ave/chunk 1 1000000 1000000 a1 v_atemp file 10Temperature.txt
fix             4b all ave/chunk 1 1000000 1000000 b1 v_atemp file 20Temperature.txt 
fix             5a all ave/chunk 1 2000000 2000000 a1 v_atemp file 10Temperature2.txt
fix             5b all ave/chunk 1 2000000 2000000 b1 v_atemp file 20Temperature2.txt 
fix             6a all ave/chunk 1 4000000 4000000 a1 v_atemp file 10Temperature4.txt 
fix             6b all ave/chunk 1 4000000 4000000 b1 v_atemp file 20Temperature4.txt
```

For this I am getting the error:

```
Two fix ave commands using same compute
chunk/atom command in incompatible ways.
```

I don't know how to fix this error. I tried to follow the document but I wasn't able to find a fix or I wasn't able to understand much from it. If anyone came across the same error please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the error says is that you are using the same `compute chunk/atom` command multiple times in different `fix ave/chunk` commands, which is not allowed.

From your code snippet, it seems that you have multiple `fix ave/chunk` commands using the same `compute chunk/atom` commands (*a1* and *b1*), but with different averaging parameters. LAMMPS cannot keep track of multiple averaging operations on the same chunks simultaneously, hence the error.

To fix this issue, you should create separate `compute chunk/atom` commands for each of your `fix ave/chunk` commands. Here's an example of how you might modify your script:

```
compute a1 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 10.0 units box
compute a2 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 10.0 units box
compute a3 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 10.0 units box

compute b1 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 20.0 units box 
compute b2 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 20.0 units box 
compute b3 all chunk/atom bin/1d x lower 20.0 units box 

fix 4a all ave/chunk 1 1000000 1000000 a1 v_atemp file 10Temperature.txt
fix 5a all ave/chunk 1 2000000 2000000 a2 v_atemp file 10Temperature2.txt
fix 6a all ave/chunk 1 4000000 4000000 a3 v_atemp file 10Temperature4.txt 

fix 4b all ave/chunk 1 1000000 1000000 b1 v_atemp file 20Temperature.txt
fix 5b all ave/chunk 1 2000000 2000000 b2 v_atemp file 20Temperature2.txt 
fix 6b all ave/chunk 1 4000000 4000000 b3 v_atemp file 20Temperature4.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is clear to me now. Thanks a lot!